# Python Tkinter pasting image ValueError: cannot determine region size; use 4-item box

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I am attempting to create a simple photo editing application that allows a user to paste a logo onto a selected image.

However, when I try to use the .paste function to paste the logo onto the current image I get the error "ValueError: cannot determine region size; use 4-item box".

Help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you fellow coders.

```
# PHOTO EDITING SCREEN
def edit_screen():
    # REFERENCE GLOBAL WINDOW
    global home_window, current_image, image_counter, all_files, image_container, canvas, add_images_button_count, \
        max_image

    # CLEAR PREVIOUS WINDOW CANVAS
    clear_screen()

    # SPECIFY WINDOW SIZE
    home_window.geometry("600x450")

    # CREATES TOP FRAME AND DOESN'T ALLOW WINDOW SHRINKAGE
    header_frame = Frame(home_window, width=600, height=50, bd=5, bg="grey")
    header_frame.grid(row=0)

    # BUTTONS
    close = Button(header_frame, text="Close App", bg="white", fg="blue", command=close_app)
    close.place(relx=0.015, rely=0.2, anchor="nw")

    back = Button(header_frame, text="Back", bg="white", fg="blue", command=back_button)
    back.place(relx=0.13, rely=0.2, anchor="nw")

    add_text = Button(header_frame, text="Add Text", bg="white", fg="blue", command=add_text_button)
    add_text.place(relx=0.38, rely=0.2, anchor="nw")

    add_logo = Button(header_frame, text="Add Logo", bg="white", fg="blue", command=add_logo_button)
    add_logo.place(relx=0.485, rely=0.2, anchor="nw")

    clear = Button(header_frame, text="Clear", bg="white", fg="blue", command=clear_edits)
    clear.place(relx=0.63, rely=0.2, anchor="n")

    save = Button(header_frame, text="Save", bg="blue", fg="white", command=save_button)
    save.place(relx=0.985, rely=0.2, anchor="ne")

    # MULTIPLE IMAGE ERROR HANDLING
    try:
        # LOGIC TO DISPLAY EACH PICTURE
        # ACCESS CURRENT IMAGE
        f = all_files[image_counter]
        # OPEN AS IMAGE
        current_image = Image.open(f)
        # TK PHOTO
        resized_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(current_image.resize((500, 400)))
        # PLACE IMAGE ON CANVAS
        image_container = canvas.create_image(300, 210, image=resized_img)
    except IndexError:
        # RESET IMAGE BUTTON COUNT VARIABLE
        add_images_button_count = 0
        # RESET MAX IMAGE COUNT VARIABLE
        max_image = []
        # RESET IMAGE COUNTER
        image_counter = 0
        # REDIRECT TO HOME SCREEN SINCE NO MORE PHOTOS EXIST
        home_screen()

    # RUN A NON RESIZEABLE TKINTER WINDOW
    home_window.resizable(False, False)
    # CLOSING WINDOW PROTOCOL
    home_window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", close_app)
    # RUN WINDOW
    home_window.mainloop()

# UPLOAD LOGO
def add_logo_function(x_logo_position, y_logo_position):
    # REFERENCE GLOBAL VARIABLES
    global canvas, current_image, image_container
    # SPECIFY FILE TYPES
    filetypes = [('JPG Files', '*.jpg'), ('PNG Files', '*.png')]
    # OPEN FILE EXPLORER AND ALLOW USER TO SELECT LOGO
    filename = askopenfilename(filetypes=filetypes)
    # OPEN AS IMAGE
    img = Image.open(filename)
    # RESIZE IMAGE
    img_resized = img.resize((100, 100))
    # TK PHOTO IMAGE
    img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img_resized)
    # PASTE LOGO ONTO CURRENT IMAGE
    current_image.paste(img, (x_logo_position.get(), y_logo_position.get()))
```

Comment: You can't do anything with an `ImageTk.PhotoImage` object other than hand it off to Tkinter to be displayed by a widget; it's unsuitable as a parameter to `.paste()`.  Use the original `Image` object instead - `img_resized`.